# Upgrade to Magento 2.2.6 to Magento 2.3.1 Init vector must be a string of 32 bytes

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.6, magento-upgrade, magento2.3.1

I have upgrade magneto 2.2.6 to magento 2.3.1 and found "***Unable to unserialize value. Error: Syntax error***" error during run the `php bin/magneto` command in terminal

[image]

And browser gets 
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearing redis cache `redis-cli flushall`

This should be part of the steps outlined in the upgrade document 
(https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html). The command should be run after `composer update` and before `bin/magento cache:clean`