# After login redirect to dashboard load for ever for administrators

Tags: magento2, admin, dashboard

When i try to login my Magento 2.3.5 backoffice with administrators role account it never finish his redirection .

After a while got a 503 Backend fetch failed
[image]

I got nothing in exception log , and the only critical log that i found is  "Init vector must be a string of 32 bytes" in system.log. And it is here for a long time. Someone face this kind of issue ?

Comment: you need to find details of the error: 50* error is an error that your webserver has made. Subsequently, if the webserver has some log enabled, then you should be able to see the details of the error in question, then we may be able to help indeed

Comment: I don't know how to search the varnish log with the  XID number, any advice ?

Comment: it is not vanish, but rather nginx or apache

Comment: Ok backend side . Got only this error. [13-Sep-2022 10:26:18 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'xsl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[13-Sep-2022 10:26:18 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'imagick' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[13-Sep-2022 10:26:18 UTC] PHP Warning:  Version warning: Imagick was compiled against ImageMagick version 1690 but version 1691 is loaded. Imagick will run but may behave surprisingly in Unknown on line 0

Comment: php logs may help?

Comment: It was the php errors logs , no nginx error . And when i check the access.log , get a 499 code on request for dashboard admin , so client side close connection. I can see a 'Init vector must be a 32 byte" in system.log of magento.

Comment: looks like you're in luck see https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/272578/upgrade-to-magento-2-2-6-to-magento-2-3-1-init-vector-must-be-a-string-of-32-byt

Comment: Done it yesterday :(

Answer (score 0):

You have found out one error in your webserver that seems to be linked to the  cache.

If an issue due to the cache seems persistent, we have 2 fallbacks that are worth to explore in your case:

1. clear the `var/cache` folder physically (that may mean you possibly would want to look at underlying issues with persmissions on your server)
2. flush redis cache `redis-cli flushall`. I understand you did this already

If none of this works, I sussgest to run the command

`bin/magento module:status` and print here the result here in the event it would return an error that would be useful for us

Comment: No error but tons of module . You want the list ?

Comment: no unfortunately, we are in dead-end now, apologies, nothing more I can do from here

Comment: you try , thank for the time

Answer (score 0):

You need to simply flush the cache

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

And once your cache is flushed, restart the varnish and mysql.

Comment: Done , not enough